# Must declare the scalar variable @DateField2

Tags: c#, sql

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dateType = DateFieldDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string DateField1 = DateTextBox.Text;
    string DateField2 = dateSelection2Text.Text;
    string DateFiled = "DateFiled";

    if (dateType == "DateFiled")
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateFiled", TypeCode.String, DateFiled));
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateField1", TypeCode.String, DateField1));
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateFie1d2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_repopulate WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateFiled) BETWEEN " +
            "CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateField1) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateField2)";
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I'm trying to perform a SQL query on a database.  I was getting an error indicating that the types DateFiled and DateField1 were incompatible even though all the elements are text. I went in and tried to fix that with the CONVERT(VARCHAR... but now it's coming up with a new error on @DateField2, that it is not declared.  To me, it looks like it is set up exactly the same as the other two parameters.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Your parameters should also have the "@" character.

Comment: They actually don't when using SqlDataSouce.SelectParameters.Add to add the parameters though they do when using sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue.  I tried it just to see and it didn't work.  Thanks though.

Comment: I'm using SqlDataSource in order to be able to present the results of the query through GridView.  Is there a better or easier way to do that?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spelling issue..

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("DateFie1d2", TypeCode.String, DateField2));
```

`DateFie1d2` instead of `DateField2`